# I'm trying to get my navigation menu to slide left and push body with it

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I'm completely new to jQuery, and I'm trying to write a script that will push my navigation menu out from the right hand side of the screen towards the left, and push the rest of the body with it.

I have been following this tutorial: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/slide-and-push-menus/

I'm not really sure what I'm doing, or exactly which CSS classes I should be using in the javascript, as all of the different menu options/examples have the codes mixed together which isn't really helpful if you're not particularly experienced with coding.

I know exactly what I want the code to do, but I'm way out of my depth applying it to my own Wordpress theme – could anyone give me pointers as to what I'm doing wrong?

So far I have the following CSS:

```
@media only screen
and (min-width : 0px)
and (max-width : 1080px) {

    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
        left: 0;
    }

    body-push {left: -240px;}

    img.standard.logo {
        height: 38px;
        width: 342px;
    }

    /* RESPONSIVE NAVIGATION MENU */

    img.menu.button {
        position:relative;
        display:block;
        width:25px;
        height:25px;
        background-size: 100%;
    }

    nav.header-nav {
        right:-240px;
        z-index:10;
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        width:250px;
        height:100%;
        float:right;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;

        background-color:#1D1D1F;
        list-style:none;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), 0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    }

    nav.header-nav nav.header-nav-open {
        right:0px;
    }
}
```

I have taken / adapted the following javascript:

```
img.menu.button.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( body, 'body-push' );
    classie.toggle( menuRight, 'nav.header-nav-open' );
    disableOther( 'showRightPush' );
};
```

My site header:

```
<header class="header">
    <!-- LOGOS -->
    <a href="#">
        <img class="standard logo" src="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Lucie_Averill_Photography_Logo-2.png">
        <img class="white logo" src="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Lucie_Averill_Photography_Logo_White.png"></a>
    <!-- LOGOS -->
    <img class="menu button" src="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Menu.png">
    <!-- HEADER NAVIGATION MENU -->
    <nav class="header-nav">
        <div class="menu-header-menu-container">
            <ul id="menu-header-menu" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-463">
                    <a href="#">WORK</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-584"><a href="#">LANDSCAPES</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-473"><a href="#">SEASCAPES</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-478"><a href="#">MACRO</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-477"><a href="#">CITIES</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-475"><a href="#">LONG EXPOSURE</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-480"><a href="#">MISCELLANEOUS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-10"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-464"><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-923">
                    <a href="#">SOCIAL</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-11"><a target="_blank" href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-924"><a href="#">INSTAGRAM</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-15"><a target="_blank" href="#">FLICKR</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-14"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your `JavaScript` code. `img` will be `undefined` and the method of writing a JavaScript function is also incorrect.

1. Add `id` attribute to your menu `img`

   `<img id="menuLeft" class="menu button" src="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Menu.png">`
2. Create a JavaScript object for menu

   `var menuLeft = document.getElementById( 'menuLeft' );`
3. Access the object `menuLeft` to trigger sliding effect

   `menuLeft.onclick = function() {
       classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
       classie.toggle( body, 'body-push' );
       classie.toggle( menuRight, 'nav.header-nav-open' );
       disableOther( 'showRightPush' );
   };`

**Update**

Since its a third party plugin, you need to include css (http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/css/default.css) and js (http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/js/classie.js) files for sliding menu.

Comment: Hi Samir, thanks for your answer – that makes sense but for some reason it isn't having any effect. The script is definitely enqueued correctly in my functions.php

Comment: Can you post if there is any javascript error from console?

Comment: Ah yes there is: " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null " and that's for: "menu-toggle.js:3"

Comment: That's where the error is. `img` is `null` in your code because there is no object  created with name as `img`. Did you try the modified code in my post?

Comment: Yes I did, and I'm referring to it in my stylesheet as "img#menuLeft.menu.button" – is that correct?  Could it also maybe have something to do with "nav.header-nav-open"?

Comment: In stylesheet, you can just add `#menuLeft` and it will work. Have you included css (`http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/css/default.css`) and js (`http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/js/classie.js`) files for sliding menu?

Comment: Oh, no I didn't - I just tried adding them to my current JS and CSS files, but it didn't work. Do I have to enqueue them separately? It seems like a lot of code.

Comment: Since you are using external plugin `classie`, you need to download and include supporting files to make it work. Download the plugin from http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/slide-and-push-menus/. You will be able to make it work in few mins :)

Comment: Ah right, shows how much I have to learn! I thought classie was a sub-category of jQuery code or something, haha. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I could help :)